# How can I publish my Protobuf Schema to HERE OLP China?

Tags: proto, here-olp

I have my Protobuf Schema published to http://platform.here.com and I would like to publish the same schema to https://platform.hereolp.cn, but I cannot find any documentation how to do it.

The only documentation I have found is this one: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/archetypes/dev_guide/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to publish my schema. I downloaded different set of credentials (`credentials.properties`) from https://platform.hereolp.cn, similar as it is written [here](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/sdk-developer-guide/dev_guide/topics/get-credentials.html), and then saved it to `~/.here` directory.

I also switched to the latest HERE Wagon Plugin 1.6.1 as it is described in [dependency management](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/sdk-developer-guide/dev_guide/topics/dependency-management.html). I have changed version and repository url:

`<artifact.wagon.version>1.6.1</artifact.wagon.version>`

and

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT</id>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>here+artifact-service://artifact-service</url> 
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

It seems that HERE Wagon Plugin resolves repository link `here+artifact-service://artifact-service` differently depending on `credentials.properties` file.

Now the schema can be published to both web sites without code changes. I only need to change `credentials.properties` in `~/.here` directory